# Get selectors in cq5?

Tags: javascript, java, aem

how can i send selector to servlet in cq5?

```
@SlingServlet(extensions = { "json" }, methods = { "GET" }, paths = { "/apps/itt/something" })
public class SomethingServlet        
String[] selectors = request.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectors();
```

Comment: <sling:include resourceType="/apps/iph/components/embedded/quick_access" path="quick_access" addSelectors="contact-page"  />

Comment: @SlingServlet(
extensions = { "json" }, 
methods = { "GET" }, 
//paths = { "/apps/iph/quickBaContexts" },
resourceTypes = { 
  QuickAccessBarServletContextsServlet.RES_TYPE_CONTEN
  
}, 
selectors = {
  QuickAccessBarServletContextsServlet.SELECTOR_CONTACT

Comment: options="/apps/iph/quickAccessBarServlet.json"

Comment: my component should be added in different pages

Comment: i should send selector to my servlet, but i'm doing something wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In CQ5/Sling, The URI `/apps/itt/something.some.selector.json` will be regard as

- path: `/apps/itt/something`
- selector: `some.selector`
- extention: `json`

Comment: this is if i have only one selector, but i should add my component in different contexts and i should have different selectors

Comment: Remove `paths` property and use `resourceType` property only. If `paths` used, other properties will be ignored. And access with `resourceType` property without `selector` property. Refer https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html#servlet-registration

Comment: but then how to identify in which context is added my component?

Comment: No ideas how to get different selectors from dialog different locations :(

Answer (score 0):

For send selector to servlet in CQ5 you need **register** servlet using selectors. after correct register you should call servlet using selectors in URL.

Example:

```
@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/test", selectors = {"first", "second"}, extensions = "json")
public class SelectorExampleServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    RequestPathInfo requestPathInfo = request.getRequestPathInfo();
    String[] selectors = requestPathInfo.getSelectors();
    for (String selector : selectors) {
        writer.print(selector);
        writer.println(); // space
    }
} 
}
```

call servlet example:

1. localhost:4502/bin/test.first.json
2. localhost:4502/bin/test.first.second.json
3. localhost:4502/bin/test.json (without selectors)

if you use ***'resourceTypes'*** instead of **'paths'** in servlet mapping, everything will remain the same, apart mechanism of calling this servlet

good luck